# js - How to write access return value of match() in one line

Tags: javascript

**This question applies to other functions that return array as value as well.** I thought I saw a short-hand code for this:

```
var result = "12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/);
alert(result[0]);
```

So, is there a way to merge the 2 lines into 1 and remove the necessity for declaring `result`?

Comment: Did return (...)[0] not work?

Comment: @reporter if match returns null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = ("12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/) || [])[0];
```

If `match` returns `null` use empty array `[]` (because if we call `[]` in `null` it will be error);

Also we can use additional condition if we need string result

```
var result = ("12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/) || [])[0] || '';
```

```js
var result1 = ("12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/) || [])[0];

console.log(result1);

var result = ("12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/) || [])[0] || '';

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
("12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just use `[0]` with the `match()` method result **directly** like this:

```
alert("12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/) ? "12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/)[0] : "No match found");
```

**Gives --> [abc]**

And that will handle the case if no match is found:

```
alert("1234".match(/(\[.*?\])/) ? "12[abc]34".match(/(\[.*?\])/)[0] : "No match found");
```

**Gives --> No match found**

[**This is a working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sce2ys3c/).